# SharePoint Development using Angular JS and .Net Web Api

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating a site in SharePoint using Angular js and it will communicate with the .net Web Api.

The web api will pull the data from database and give it back to the sharePoint site.

But I am not getting any response from the .net web api. It goes inside the web api call and returns the data but no response coming in the sharepoint site.

The error that I get is "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied". I have tried sending the data from the web api in jsonp format also but of no success. If I try to make a call through a html page outside of sharepoint server, then I get the response.

Below is the code snippet that I am using in my code to make the call.

```
$http.get('url')
         .success(function (response) 
 $scope.members = response

}).error(function (status) {

})
```